# Run all sql files with Chef

Tags: sql, ruby, chef-infra

Hello i need help i made a command that should read all the sql files inside of the sql_dumps folder but it isnt working.. here is what i got.

```
execute "Run_SQL_Files" do
  dirResults = Dir.glob("/tmp/sql_dumps/*.sql") 
  var = 0
  while var < 15 do
    var = var + 1 
    command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba source" + dirResults[var]
    # Already tried this also
    # command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba < "  dirResults[var]
    puts dirResults[var]
  end
end
```

I'am not very familiar with ruby. This is the error i received

```
 default: Errno::ENOENT
 default: -------------
 default: No such file or directory - Run_SQL_Files
 default:
 default: Resource Declaration:
 default: ---------------------
 default: # In /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/main/recip
 default.rb
 default:
 default: 214:
 default: 215: execute "Run_SQL_Files" do
 default: 216:   dirResults = Dir.glob("/tmp/sql_dumps/*.sql")
 default: 217:   var = 0
 default: 218:   while var < 15 do
 default: 219:     var = var + 1
 default: 220:     puts `mysql --user=root --password=toomba source
 {dirResults[var]}`
 default: 221:     puts dirResults[var]
 default: 222:   end
 default: 223:   #command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba < "
 iles
 default: 224: end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the error ? not working is not an issue description

Comment: Sorry i had forgotten it, but i edited my post! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misconception here about how Chef compiles resources. You are expecting Chef to execute the command 15 times, but that's not how Chef operates. Chef runs in two phases - the execution phase, and the compilation phase. During the compilation phase (which runs first), the Ruby is evaluated and resources are added to the resource collection. With some exceptions, this phase does **not** alter the state of the system. So given your recipe:

```rb
execute "Run_SQL_Files" do
  dirResults = Dir.glob("/tmp/sql_dumps/*.sql") 
  var = 0
  while var < 15 do
    var = var + 1 
    command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba source" + dirResults[var]
    # Already tried this also
    # command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba < "  dirResults[var]
    puts dirResults[var]
  end
end
```

That is functionally equivalent to a recipe that was written like this (after the compilation phase completes)"

```rb
execute "Run_SQL_Files" do
  command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba source /tmp/sql_dumps/15.sql"
end
```

Notice that Chef is only going to utilize the **last** value for the `command` attribute. That is because Chef executes in two phases (as already mentioned).

Using conditional logic and loops inside of a resource definition is almost always going to cause problems. In this example, you need to compile the command **outside** of the execute resource. Each SQL command you want to execute needs to have it's own `execute` block. Here's a simple, refactored example:

```rb
Dir["/tmp/sql_dumps/*.sql"].each do |path|
  execute "run_sql_#{path}" do
    command "mysql --user=root --password=toomba < #{path}"
  end
end
```

This will put 15 (assumption from OP) execute resources in the resource collection, and execute them in order.