# Giving different installation path for java in chef recipe

Tags: java, path, chef-infra, recipe

I am trying installing java with the help of below code but by default it installs in /usr/java/ directory.. I want it to be installed on a separate directory for example /u01/app.

## Recipe

```rb
# Remove old environment then notify new environment to be created
ruby_block "delete_environement" do
  block do
    editBashrc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/home/oracle/.bash_profile")
    editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*#{node['java']['home']} environment settings.*$/)
    editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook sun_java.*$/)
    editBashrc.search_file_delete_line(/^.*export JAVA_HOME=.*$/)
    editBashrc.write_file 
  end
  action :create
end

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm" do
  source "http://#######/java/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm"
  mode "0755"
end

rpm_package "javaRPM" do    
  source :"#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm"
  only_if {::File.exists?("#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm")}
  owner :oracle 
  action :install   
end

# update oracle bash profile ~/.bash_profile

execute "create_environment" do
  user "oracle"
  command "echo -e '#{node['java']['home']} environment settings\n#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook oracle_java\nexport JAVA_HOME=#{node['java']['home']}' >> ~/.bash_profile"
  command "echo -e '#{node['java']['home']} environment settings\n#Auto-generated by Chef Cookbook oracle_java\nexport PATH=$PATH:#{node['java']['home']}/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile"
  command "source ~/.bash_profile"
end

file "javaRPM-cleanup" do
  path "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm"
  action :delete
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is your understanding of the `execute` resource. As I explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260386/run-all-sql-files-with-chef):

> Notice that Chef is only going to utilize the last value for the command attribute. That is because Chef executes in two phases - compilation and execution.

So, only the last command in that sequence (`source ~/.bash_profile`) will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how execute works :) but i still don't know how to change the installation path for java from /usr/bin to the directory i want